# How to deep join a tuple into a string

Tags: python

I want to convert a tuple to a semicolon-separated string. Easy.

```
tup = (1,2)
';'.join(map(str,tup))
```

Output:

```
'1;2'
```

If one of the tuple entries is itself a tuple, however, I get something like this:

```
'1;(2, 3)'
```

I don't want that comma, I want a semicolon, and also I'd like to select the parentheses characters as well.

I want this:

```
'1;{2;3}'
```

Is there an easy way to deep-join a tuple of tuples nested to any depth, specifying both the separator (';' in the example) and the parenthes ('{' and '}' in the example above)?

Note that I do *not* want this, which this question was marked as a duplicate of:

```
'1,2,3'
```

I also need to handle strings with commas in them, so i can't use `replace`:

```
flatten((1,('2,3',4)))
'1;{2,3;4}'
```

Comment: What do you mean by select the parentheses? Show us expected output. Looks like you can create a recursive function.

Comment: I also thought the duplicate was wrong. but that happens sometimes.

Comment: Yeah, this has nothing to do with flattening... an odd dupe.

Comment: If the string is the only problem and if you're sure that patterns such as `'('`, `'('` or `', '` couldn't be encountered in string conversions of atomic elements, you could also use `replace()` : `yourstring.replace('(', ';').replace(')', ';').replace(', ', ';')`.

Comment: I can't use `replace` - the reason I want to specify the separator is in case a comma appears in an element.

Comment: @COLDSPEED this is an absolutely incorrect flagging of a question.

Comment: Define a function such as `f = lambda t: '(' + ','.join(map(str, t)) +')' if hasattr(t, '__iter__') else str(t)` and map `f` to your sequence: `';'.join(map(f, a))` where `a=(1,(2,3))`. Since this question was closed, I cannot provide a more complete answer on how to handle parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

Recursion to the rescue!

```
def jointuple(tpl, sep=";", lbr="{", rbr="}"):
    return sep.join(lbr + jointuple(x) + rbr if isinstance(x, tuple) else str(x) for x in tpl)
```

#### Usage:

```
>>> jointuple((1,('2,3',4)))
'1;{2,3;4}'
```

Comment: You might want to add parameters for the braces and separator: `def jointuple(tpl, sep=';', lbr='{', rbr='}')`, unless I misunderstood what OP means by selecting the braces. +1 regardless.